# What model does Watson natural language processing uses for topic modeling? LDA?

Tags: topic-modeling, watson-nlu

I'm learning about Watson's [NLU](https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/natural-language-understanding) but I can't find any reference as to what model it's using for topic modeling. Is it LDA? pLSA? Any other? I understand the question is general, but it's very important to know what's under the hood...

Comment: afaik it uses SiRE, but don't quote me on that. https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/28191/what-is-the-watson-relationship-extraction-service/

Comment: You can use Watson Knowledge Studio to build your own models (which can import CAS models from WEX).

Answer (score 0):

Watson NLU categories and concepts (which I assume is what you mean by topic modeling) use custom machine learning models that do not directly correspond to either LDA or pLSA.

Comment: Where do you have this information from? Would be interesting to learn more about it.